# Segmentation fault returning OGR Layer object from function in Python

Tags: python, ogr, osgeo

I have a simple programme that processes points from a Geopackage layer. On a first attempt I encapsulated file access into a function:

```
from osgeo import ogr

pointsFile = "points.gpkg"

def getPoints():

    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("GPKG")
    dataSource = driver.Open(pointsFile, 0)
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer(0)
    print("Returning layer")
    return layer

def main():

    layer = getPoints()
    print("Number of points to process: ", layer.GetFeatureCount())


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Which fails with a segmentation fault when it returns the layer object:

```
$ python3 testReturn.py
Returning layer
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, with file access inside `main`:

```
from osgeo import ogr

pointsFile = "points.gpkg"

def main():

    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("GPKG")
    dataSource = driver.Open(pointsFile, 0)
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer(0)
    print("Number of points to process: ", layer.GetFeatureCount())


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

the programme runs as expected:

```
$ python3 testDirect.py
Number of points to process:  21872
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested the code with `GDB` and the segmentation fault  occurs when when calling:

> layer.GetFeatureCount()

Some extra debugging information:

> Starting program: /usr/bin/python3 testReturn.py
>
> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
>
> Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
>
> Returning layer
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007ffff5c42298 in OGR_L_GetFeatureCount () from /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.20
> (gdb)

Comment: Very interesting. Basically, when the function exits the `dataSource` object is destroyed and it breaks up the `layer` object. Looks like a bug with this library.

Comment: It's actually not a bug with the library. See https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas and https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/7175.